Create IVR bot with recordings
I am working on creating an IVR bot that will eventually integrate with ChatGPT.
I have a server with code to respond to the incoming call that is working correctly.
When I call the number we can go back and forth, however, I am unable to record both the customer and IVR prompt since it is an incoming call. I also am not able to get call events to modify the call once it is progress. it is only calling the webhook once the call is complete
The <record> verb seems to only record a voicemail and not both channels in the call.
Thank you!

Can you please explain what you've tried so far and where you are stuck now?  This guideline explains how to ask good questions.

Hi there- I was able to resolve this by using the dial verb to call another twilio number linked to the voice bot. I'm having an issue now with linking the call SID's together, but I did that in another ticket.

I was able to resolve this by using the dial verb to call another twilio number linked to the voice bot and using the record parameter on that Dial verb
